# What does "stabilize" mean in Conway's game of life?

Tags: soft-question, definition, automata

In wikipedia's article about Conway's game of Life, it often talks about a pattern eventually *stabilizing*, there's even a page about a type of seed called Methuselah which is "defined" as a small pattern of initial live cells that takes long to *stabilize*. However a definition of what it means to *stabilize* cannot be found. A possible definition would be that a pattern stabilizes if at some point it enters a cycle. But an example given  in that page would not fit, since there are gliders that will prevent cycles from happening. How can "stabilize" then be defined?

Comment: I am not an expert in the terminology here... but, from a general mathematical viewpoint, "stabilize" _might_ mean "enter a (finite) cycle", that does not involve physical motion. Or, it _might_ allow physical motion as part of the cycle... yes, which could depend on whether the "universe" was wrap-around or not... So, yes, most glider (as far as I know) just travel in a straight line, which will wrap around if the universe is wrap-around, or will travel off to "infinity" if the universe is the Euclidean plane. I've not kept track these last years to know of other possibilities... :)

Comment: The Wikipedia article has dozens of references, including [ConwayLife.com](https://www.conwaylife.com). Have you consulted (m)any of them? (Knowing where you've checked without success can help people avoid duplicating your effort.)

Answer (score 3):

We say a pattern has stabilized when it becomes obvious that the population has stopped growing. For example, we say the R-pentomino stabilizes at step 1103 because at this point it consists of just gliders and oscillators, and it is clear that the gliders will never collide with each other or with any oscillators

Comment: Taken from: http://www.math.com/students/wonders/life/life.html